# window.onload not triggering on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have this code below, which doesn't seem to run on iOS devices (iPhone and iPad, tested on iPhone 6/6 Plus and iPad Air 2, on both Safari and Chrome). The console responds with an error for unexpected token ')' and anonymous function, but this code works for Chrome on Windows Desktop and Andriod devices.

```
$(window).on('load', () => {
     //rest of code
}
```

I'm not really sure what could the error be, but it seems to be iOS specific. I've tried $(document).on('ready'), along with window.onLoad(function(){}) but they didn't work either. Thank you!

**Edit**: I prefer the window onload function because I'm using a loading page too and want all the img and video elements to be loaded before displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update to this question, I managed to find the problem and thought that I should reply to the question for closure. iOS (at least on the earlier versions) doesn't seem to support () => {} so I had to use function(){} instead.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
     //rest of code
}
```